# Automatic `p4 resolve` after `p4 sync` in p4v?

Tags: triggers, merge, perforce

I would like to set up some kind of userspace trigger for my local `p4v` that automatically calls `p4 resolve -as` (safe resolve) after it calls `p4 sync` when run from the "Get Latest Revision" or "Get Revision..." menu item.

Is there a way to do this? I am losing a lot of time resolving trivial changes or even checking whether there is an unmerged file, and I consider `p4 resolve -as` to be always safe on this project.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script that runs `p4 sync` followed by `p4 resolve -as`, and then install it as a P4V custom tool.  Custom tools can be passed selected files or folders as input arguments, so your script would know which files to operate on.  Custom tools are available from context menus.

Perhaps not as convenient as a client-side trigger (which Perforce does not have), but it does give you the option of choosing a regular sync or a sync+resolve.

Comment: I do things like this all the time. I also have shell scripts that run sequences of p4 commands so I can type one thing and have all kinds of things happen. That's the main thing I like about Perforce.

Comment: I should add that I already have custom tools that do this and more; the drawback is that they are always at the bottom of the context menu and they don't prevent accidental use of the original entry. For some reason I am unable to edit my question to reflect that.